# Optics. Best way to concentrate light into delimited surface

Tags: lithography

I'm doing some experiments with 400nm UV lithography using color LCD and mono LCD and works very well (5", 2k or 4k resolution), but I'm guessing how to optimize the light source.
Right now I'm using UV lamp as a source,  but I think some light is wasted in this arrangement.

I have two references for this purpose:

- UV LED grids with plastic collimators are being used in 3D printers, but to me seems like too much for this purpose.
- lateral LEDS perpendicular to the output, directed to plastic diffusser like the way used in LCD monitor / TV backlight.
- DLP projectors. I don't try it, they are expensive.

Why this second way is not used in 3D printing? For me seems more cost effective, but I don't know about efficiency. There are better ways to do this?

Comment: Thanks "Transistor" for improving the style and grammar

Comment: What aspect of the performance are you trying to improve? Why is the efficiency of the UV source so important?

Comment: the LUX measured at the target point (the LCD) are log with distance to the focus (UV focus), and it is needed to pull apart focus to cover all the target. This means that a lot of light is wasted. We are generating 50w, and that is not only consumption but also heat, which implies the need for a heatsink.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are doing?  Exposing a masked surface perhaps?   Are you concerned about heating your mask?   Does your system use any kind of scanning mechanisms or is it purely direct illumination?

Comment: UV lithography to expose electronic PCB photoresist boards with mask, and same foundation as SLA 3D printing. My old UV exposer has UV actinic tubes, and also I'm working with LED UV, but as I said this not seems optimal to me. What if I change white LED from a backlight to UV led?